# Making a multiple objects appear one after another using Firebase

Tags: firebase

**Edited a bit to try and explain this better**

I have a problem in which i'm not sure how to even start to go about solving. It's also very hard to explain.
Basically, I have a storage location in Firebase that looks like this:

[image]

(in this image it only shows one storage location. later there is another with a title of 'Test' and a body of 'As you can see, this messes up')
What I want to do is have it so that when I use this code:

#### html file:

```
<div class="span8" id="verticalLine">
        <h2 id="main-header"><center>Latest news</center></h2>
        <div id="newsDivHead"></div>
        <br/>
        <div id="newsDiv"></div>
        <script>
        var newsData = new Firebase("https://agn.firebaseio.com/web/news/mc/")
        newsData.limit(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
            var message = snapshot.val();
            $('<div/>').text(message.body).appendTo($('#newsDiv'));
            $('<div/>').text(message.title).appendTo($('#newsDivHead'));
            $('#newsDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#newsDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
        });
        </script>
        <!---
            $('<div/>').text(message.body).prepend($('<em/>')
            .text(message.title+': ')).appendTo($('#newsDiv'));
        $('#newsDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#newsDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
        });
        --->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to give a result like this:

[image]

Notice the formatting of the title and the break.
But unfortunately it comes out like this:

[image]

What I want to happen is it formats the value stored in `message.title` so that it appears above the `message.body` and is formatted in the  format (or something similar). I have realised that this is not possible using the two div tags, I can only use the one. 
So what do I do? Is this even possible? The title and text are in the 'varibles' (firebase ref) message.title and message.body respectivley (As you can see in the code.)
Any Help gladly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with Firebase. Could you show us the HTML it's generating, and the HTML it _should_ generate? Screenshots are less-than-useful in this case.

Comment: It's not generating HTML, everything is pulled from Firebase. You are still correct, Firebase is not the problem. It's my JavaScript that is the problem. Let me edit the post and make myself clearer. Cheers. :D

Comment: Oh, it's not generating HTML? Really. Are you sure about that? So... what is the browser rendering? What is your JavaScript manipulating? (Hint: the answer to both questions rhymes with "HTML.")

Comment: It's not _generating_ HTML, rather _manipulating_ the HTML. There is a div tag in the html that looks like this: `<div id="newsDivHead"></div><br/><div id="newsDiv"></div>` which the JavaScript is manipulating. So basically, it is taking the data from Firebase and putting it into a CSS-formatted div. So I guess you _could_ say that it is generating HTML, but really the HTML is already there but as a value of 'null', which this JavaScript changes.

Comment: Sure, manipulating, whatever. You still haven't answered my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with Firebase, but is rather a HTML issue. You have two divs in your HTML, one to show titles and another to show content. Don't do this and use CSS classes instead of visually separate titles from text.

```html
<div class="span8" id="verticalLine">
    <h2 id="main-header"><center>Latest news</center></h2>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var newsData = new Firebase("https://agn.firebaseio.com/web/news/mc/")
newsData.limit(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  var message = snapshot.val();
  var body = $('<div/>').class('body').text(message.body);
  var title = $('<div/>').class('title').text(message.title);
  $('<div/>').append(title).append(body).appendTo($('#content'));
});
```

In your CSS, set the styles for the classes 'body' and 'title' as you do currently for your 'newsDiv' and 'newsDivHead' IDs:

```css
.body {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```